# Show Google Sheets Cell Value in Web page

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get the value of a cell in Google Sheets and show it on a web page (in Wordpress).
It appears that you could publish individual cells in the old google sheets but I can't find how to do this now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make another sheet inside your spreadsheet
2. Delete all rows and columns except A1
3. Enter the formula = of the cell which you want to show on the web page
4. File > Publish to the Web
5. Select only the single-cell sheet that you have just created and populated

Comment: This doesn't really do what I need as it shows the sheet name, etc. 
I want to get the value of a single cell only, not the entire worksheet in an iframe. It was possible before but not on the new sheets it seems.